# Source for embedding multiplicative group of an algebraic closure of a finite field?

Tags: finite-fields, reference-request, nt.number-theory

It's easy to embed the (cyclic) multiplicative group of a finite field into the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{C}$ (or other algebraically closed field of characteristic 0): assign to a generator of the finite cyclic group a corresponding primitive root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$.    Though such embeddings are usually not unique, a fixed one is needed for example to define the Brauer character of a $p$-modular representation of a finite group.

More generally one can embed the multiplicative group $F^\times$ of an algebraic  closure $F$ of $\mathbb{F}_p$ into $\mathbb{C}^\times$.   This is somewhat less elementary and certainly less familiar.  I'd be curious to know about the historical origin of such embeddings, but my immediate question is just a reference request:

> What is a convenient modern reference for this larger type of embedding?

P.S. To clarify what I'm asking for, the *proof* of the embedding statement is not the issue (it requires some version of Zorn's Lemma, as does the original proof of existence of an algebraic closure of a finite field).   I'd expect to find an explicit statement in some book, even in the form of a structured exercise, but it's not immediately obvious where to look.    Occasionally some use is made in research papers of an embedding (without further comment).

Comment: Isn't this just a recursive construction from the finite case?

Comment: See the comments to my (wrong) answer...

Answer (score 7):

One way to construct such an embedding (although probably not the easiest) is to use Witt vectors.

For every perfect field $k$ of characteristic $p$, the ring $W(k)$ of Witt vectors over $k$ is a complete discrete valuation ring of characteristic zero with residue field $k$. It is equipped with a multiplicative map $[\cdot] : k \to W(k)$ which is a section of the residue map, so that $k^\times$ embeds in $W(k)^\times$. Now you can embed $W(\overline{\mathbf{F}_p})$ in $\mathbf{C}$ by purely formal arguments. Note this also works for other fields $k$, at least if the cardinality of $k$ is not too big.

Answer (score 2):

Choose a prime of lying over $p$ in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Then the reduction map gives an isomorphism from the roots of 1 of order prime to $p$ onto the $F^{\times}$.

Added: the proofs only require the Axiom of Dependent Choice, which is strictly weaker than the Axiom of Choice. The same is true of the construction of $F$ (for example, you could define $F$ to be the residue field at the chosen prime).

Answer (score 0):

I might be confused, but isn't that group isomorphic to the $p$-primary part of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z},$ which obviously does imbed in $\mathbb{C}^*?$

Comment: The group is indeed isomorphic to a subgroup of  $\varinjlim \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ , but every element has order relatively prime to $p$. The point is that the direct limit is taken over all the $n′s$ of the form $p^k−1$.

Comment: Ah, yes, so I was confused. I guess there is no easy way to give a direct description of that group...

Comment: The group is isomorphic to the sum of $q$-primary components of $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ for $q\ne p$. That is, $\{a/b:(b,p)=1\}/\mathbb Z$. This group obviously embeds in $\mathbb C^*$, however, I guess the problem is the isomorphism of $F^*$ and the above mentioned subgroup of $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is not canonical.

Comment: @Emil: is it obvious that that is the group? @Guillermo's comment does confirm that the existence of an embedding is soft/easy.

Comment: Well, it’s a torsion group, and its $p$-primary component is trivial. For any $q\ne p$, the $q$-primary component has rank $1$ as there are only $q$ elements of order $q$, hence it is either the Prüfer group or $C(q^n)$ for some $n$. It must be the former, as the group has elements of order $q^n$ for arbitrary $n$.

Comment: I used here the following facts of fields: in characteristic $p$, the polynomial $x^p-1=(x-1)^p$ has a unique solution. For any $q$, $x^q-1$ has at most $q$ solutions. If $(p,n)=1$, there exists a primitive $n$th roots of unity in $\mathbb F_{p^k}$ for some $k$, namely for $k$ being the order of $p$ modulo $n$. This in turn follows from the cyclicity of $\mathbb F_{p^k}^*$.

Comment: What I meant by non-canonical is that if you try to express the group as a limit of cyclic of group as in Guillermo’s comment, you have to successively chose a cyclic generator of $\mathbb F_{p^k}^*$ at each step. These choices are arbitrary, and different choices lead to a different embedding. To put it differently, every $x\in\overline{\mathbb F_p}^*$ is a primitive $n$th root of $1$ for some $(n,p)=1$, and thus it is mapped to some $a/n\in\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$, $(a,n)=1$. However, $a$ here can be anything, as there are automorphisms mapping $x$ to any other primitive $n$th root of $1$.

Comment: @Emil: Yes, the non-canonical part is clear, but I am not sure why one would hope for the existence of a canonical embedding (In fact I guess there are uncountably many such embeddings, each of them as good as any other). The description of the group is nice!

Comment: Another description of the group in question is that it’s the direct sum (not product) of the divisible groups ${\mathbb{Z}}[1/\ell]/{\mathbb{Z}}$, for all the primes $\ell$ unequal to $p$. Then you see very easily what its endomorphism ring and automorphism group are. From that you see how any two embeddings of $F^\times$ into ${\mathbb{C}}^\times$ are related.

Comment: I don't see how there could be a canonical embedding. After all, we can always precompose any embedding with an element of $Gal(\overline{F}_p/F_p)$, and that's very large.